# Laravel get next/previous record by specific column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Product model.

I want to get the next previous Product, ordered by the `name`, NOT the `id`.

This is what I have now:

```php
    public function getNextAttribute() {
        return FontFamily::select('id', 'name')->where('id', '>', $this->id)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first() ?? FontFamily::first();
    }

    public function getPreviousAttribute() {
        return FontFamily::select('id', 'name')->where('id', '<', $this->id)->orderBy('name', 'desc')->first() ?? FontFamily::latest()->first();
    }
```

However using `orderBy('name')` doesn't do the trick, as I need to get tne next not based on the `id` but based on the `name`.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: "i need to get the next based on the `id` but based on the `name`" ... can you explain this more?  can you show an example of the data you are getting to show why what you have is not correct for your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where condition should be on the name as well, not on the id:

```
    public function getNextAttribute() {
        return FontFamily::select('id', 'name')->where('name', '>', $this->name)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first() ?? FontFamily::first();
    }

    public function getPreviousAttribute() {
        return FontFamily::select('id', 'name')->where('name', '<', $this->name)->orderBy('name', 'desc')->first() ?? FontFamily::latest()->first();
    }
```